# Flutter - A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.4 pixels on the bottom

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create a homescreen for my project app with horizontal scroll view. However I'm getting this error:

```
======== Exception caught by rendering library =====================================================
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.4 pixels on the bottom.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Column Column:file:///home/.../lib/onboarding/onboarding_widget.dart:56:16
The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.

Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex, like a ListView.
```

Here is the content of onboarding_widget.dart :

```
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_widgets.dart';
import '/login_page/login_page_widget.dart';
import '/register_account/register_account_widget.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart'
    as smooth_page_indicator;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'onboarding_model.dart';
export 'onboarding_model.dart';

class OnboardingWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnboardingWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OnboardingWidgetState createState() => _OnboardingWidgetState();
}

class _OnboardingWidgetState extends State<OnboardingWidget> {
  late OnboardingModel _model;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int get pageViewCurrentIndex => _model.pageViewController != null &&
          _model.pageViewController!.hasClients &&
          _model.pageViewController!.page != null
      ? _model.pageViewController!.page!.round()
      : 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _model = createModel(context, () => OnboardingModel());

    logFirebaseEvent('screen_view', parameters: {'screen_name': 'onboarding'});
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _model.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    context.watch<FFAppState>();

    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).secondaryBackground,
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(24.0, 24.0, 24.0, 20.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                          ? 'assets/images/Copy_of_Copy_of_Vastepay.png'
                          : 'assets/images/Copy_of_Copy_of_Vastepay_(1).png',
                      width: 150.0,
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0),
                          child: PageView(
                            controller: _model.pageViewController ??=
                                PageController(initialPage: 0),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: 100.0,
                                height: 100.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0),
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/3d-business-girl-chatting-online.png',
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                    .size
                                                    .width *
                                                0.7,
                                            height: 300.0,
                                            fit: BoxFit.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                'i8hl2uua' /* Send money in seconds */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .displaySmall
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.normal,
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                'hxtwax0y' /* Create budgets that you can ti... */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodySmall,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 100.0,
                                height: 100.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0),
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/3d-casual-life-wallet-with-banknots-and-coins-flying-around.png',
                                            width: 300.0,
                                            height: 300.0,
                                            fit: BoxFit.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                'mjy3ljln' /* Keep Track of Spending */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .displaySmall
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.normal,
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                'uf9k1spp' /* Easily add transactions and as... */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodySmall,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 100.0,
                                height: 100.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding:
                                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                                  0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 30.0),
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                            'assets/images/casual-life-3d-blue-shopping-bag-in-air-1.png',
                                            width: 300.0,
                                            height: 250.0,
                                            fit: BoxFit.none,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                '9c4outzf' /* Shop in an instant */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .displaySmall
                                                      .override(
                                                        fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                                                        fontWeight:
                                                            FontWeight.normal,
                                                      ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                          20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 8.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              FFLocalizations.of(context)
                                                  .getText(
                                                'q30ina4f' /* Know where your budgets are an... */,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                              style:
                                                  FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                                      .bodySmall,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0.0, 1.0),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                            child: smooth_page_indicator.SmoothPageIndicator(
                              controller: _model.pageViewController ??=
                                  PageController(initialPage: 0),
                              count: 3,
                              axisDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              onDotClicked: (i) async {
                                await _model.pageViewController!.animateToPage(
                                  i,
                                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                  curve: Curves.ease,
                                );
                              },
                              effect: smooth_page_indicator.ExpandingDotsEffect(
                                expansionFactor: 2.0,
                                spacing: 8.0,
                                radius: 16.0,
                                dotWidth: 16.0,
                                dotHeight: 4.0,
                                dotColor: Color(0x8AC6CAD4),
                                activeDotColor:
                                    FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryText,
                                paintStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0.0, 15.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                              24.0, 0.0, 24.0, 0.0),
                          child: FFButtonWidget(
                            onPressed: () async {
                              logFirebaseEvent(
                                  'ONBOARDING_PAGE_GET_STARTED_BTN_ON_TAP');
                              logFirebaseEvent('Button_navigate_to');
                              await Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageTransition(
                                  type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                                  reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                                  child: RegisterAccountWidget(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            text: FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
                              'ypt7b97g' /* Get started */,
                            ),
                            options: FFButtonOptions(
                              width: 300.0,
                              height: 55.0,
                              padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                              iconPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                  0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                              color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryText,
                              textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                  .titleSmall
                                  .override(
                                    fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                                    color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                        .secondaryBackground,
                                  ),
                              elevation: 2.0,
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                width: 1.0,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 25.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
                          'an1bjd4m' /* Have an account? */,
                        ),
                        style: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).titleSmall.override(
                              fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                              color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primaryText,
                            ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: FFButtonWidget(
                          onPressed: () async {
                            logFirebaseEvent(
                                'ONBOARDING_PAGE_LOG_IN_BTN_ON_TAP');
                            logFirebaseEvent('Button_navigate_to');
                            await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              PageTransition(
                                type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                                reverseDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                                child: LoginPageWidget(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          text: FFLocalizations.of(context).getText(
                            'kyyjftwn' /* Log in */,
                          ),
                          options: FFButtonOptions(
                            height: 40.0,
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                            iconPadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                            color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                .secondaryBackground,
                            textStyle: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context)
                                .titleSmall
                                .override(
                                  fontFamily: 'Lexend',
                                  color: FlutterFlowTheme.of(context).primary,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                            elevation: 0.0,
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              width: 0.0,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to add Expanded in some children widget as mentionned in the error, still occuring. I'm new to flutter and  at this point any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite a big piece of code, with quite a few dependencies, so it's not easy to run and reproduce, but my guess, based on the error log u've provided, is that the main column, starting at the line `56`, is given restricted height and its content takes more than provided.

If so, the easiest, not necessarily the best, solution would be to wrap it in a `SingleScrollChildView`:

```
...
body: SafeArea(
  top: true,
  child: SingleChildScrollView( // <---
    child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
...
```

If that doesn't help I would recommend trying one of the following debugging methods:

- starting the app on a platform where you can easily change the screen size, e.g., web, macos, ..., to see if the size is the issue
- commenting out portions of code if hope to find the problematic one

Comment: The SingleScrollChildView worked fine, even if it does scroll a little bit. Is ther any workaround that reduces the height of the main column ? Thanks a lot tho

Comment: The only thing you could do is trying to control the size of the content you are trying to display - image, font, ..., sizes.

You have given screen size, that you cannot control, and then some content that you want to display. So unless you can control the content, which might be painful because you probably won't work on only one fixed screen size, then you have to provide it possibility to scroll so that it fits.

Comment: The main three ways to add the scrolling are: the `SingleChildScrollView` ( fastest, easiest, least efficient), `ListView` (fast, easy, in some cases optimised (you can read more about it if you are interested)),`Slivers` (somewhat less easy to use but always optimised).